# Automatic video on boot

Tags: video, kiosk-mode

I want a video file to be open automatically on my LG tablet when it boots. Is there any app or setting in Android?

There is a video presentation that I am sending to my clients and all I want is that when client turn on the tablet, my video presentation starts playing automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Could probably be realized using [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm):

- Condition: Boot completed (or Monitor Start)
- Task: Start App

Not sure if you can specify a video file directly here. But there might at least be some video player supporting to automatically start playing the latest playlist, which should make up for it.

You can find a free 7-day-trial of tasker on their homepage -- or try alternative automation apps such as e.g. [Llama - Location Profiles](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama). Another possibility is to create the profile with *Tasker*, and then export it using the [Tasker App Factory](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.appfactory); this way you'ld get a "free version app" of your profile to distribute on the tablets.

Comment: Wow, I haven't seen the Tasker App Factory before! That's looks like a really nifty app; I'll have to try it out.

Comment: Yupp, do so! It even permits you to sell the results :) Ooops, close to off topic now #D But the main thing is: You'd only need to buy Tasker once (for your account), and could provide the profiles for all the other accounts for free.

Answer (score 0):

[VideoKiosk](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.burningthumb.premiervideokiosk&hl=en) may be what you are looking for.